# Como puedo hacer que en la camara aparezca un filtro

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo una app en android sudios con java sobre el horoscopo y quiero que al abrir la camara aparezca algun filtro, o de estrallas o luna o algo parecido o la posibilidad de que el fondo sea una imagen y salga la persona por delante del fondo. Se puede hacer?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: La mayoría de preguntas del estilo: *¿Se puede hacer ...?* Se pueden responder por si o no y no aportan a la comunidad. ¿Qué intentaste?